# Several MAX values based on another column value

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to write a SQL query in MS ACCESS and I've narrowed it down to the table below, but can't seem to get the last thing right without making several extremely large querys.

**Here's the strucuture of thetable I'm trying to query:**

[image]

**The results I want**: MemberId and year where memberId had most visits in that year.(That is which memberId had most visits 2014, which had most visits 2015 etc..and I also want the relevant year to be shown in the result)

Thanks!

Comment: Cn you show us your try,no matter how wrong?

Comment: this group by should work . select memberId, Year, max(totalVisits)
from myTable 
group by memberId, Year

Comment: What about ties? E.g. MemberID 5 and 7 for 2014.

Comment: My Query only manages to get the max value for one year, so it's kinda useless. I tried your query now radar, problem is it returns several entries per year, I want only the one with highest visits for every year

Comment: Managed to solve it with help of another question link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to determine `MAX(Visits)` by `year` in a subquery, then `JOIN` to that:

```
SELECT a.*,b.Max_Visits
FROM YourTable a
JOIN (SELECT Year,MAX(Visits) AS Max_Visits
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY Year
     ) b
 ON a.Year = b.Year
 AND a.Visits = b.Max_Visits
```

If you want to see all members and not just those that had the most visits per year, you can change from `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

If there's a tie, this returns both members.